# jQuery AJAX onclick get DOM of a specified URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I would like to make an AJAX pagination withot php and mysql, so when I click a link than I would like to get the next page DOM without reloading page and than in that DOM find the elements I need to append to the current page.
I now that jQuery IAS does this but I have a three col design and I need only one next button which onclick appends the data into the aproppriate col based on its parent class and IAS can't handle tree col layout.

So basicly something like this:

```
$('a.button').click(function(){
  var url = $('a.next').attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //or POST i don't know which one
    data: url, //or should this be the url: ?
    success: function(data){
      //data should be the DOM of the second page
      $html = $(data);
      $html.find('.col1 .child').appendTo('.col1');
      $html.find('.col2 .child').appendTo('.col3');
      $html.find('.col3 .child').appendTo('.col3');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work I just put it here to make my question undersandable.

How can I do this?

Comment: and just what is `jQuery IAS`?

Comment: jQuery Infinite Ajax Scroll

Comment: if using a plugin, say so, there are thousands of them. Hard enough to have people recognize the one you are using let alone when you create some unknown abbreviation for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it would be variable url such as

```
    $('a.button').onclick(function(){
  var url = $('a.next').attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //or POST i don't know which one
    url: url, //or should this be the url: ?
    success: function(data){
      //data should be the DOM of the second page
      $html = $(data);
      $html.find('.col1 .child').appendTo('.col1');
      $html.find('.col2 .child').appendTo('.col3');
      $html.find('.col3 .child').appendTo('.col3');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

you use data parameter to pass an object of key value pairs to the receiving end.

```
data: {key1: value1 , key2: value2}
```

Comment: Thanks the ajax part works now and the data returns the next page html, but when I do the find() part it returns an empty object as if it doesn't find the element but if I console.log(data) I see the element I trying to find

Comment: Sorry my bad I used `#` instead of `.` now it works. Thanks again.